# How to prevent having to `personal.unlockAccount()` all the time when using `geth` and `Remix`?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, remix

> How to prevent having to `personal.unlockAccount()` all the time when using `geth` and `Remix`?

I'm using `geth` and `Remix` in combination to learn contract development.

All the time, I've to switch to the terminal and enter `personal.unlockAccount()` to use `Remix`.

Is there an option to unlock the account on a permanent basis when testing things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can specify the unlock duration in unlockAccount:

```
personal.unlockAccount(addr, passwd, duration)
```

Unlock the account with the given address, password and an optional duration (in seconds).

so use for example ;     `personal.unlockAccount(addr, passwd, 300) //unlock for 5 minutes`

```
web3.personal.unlockAccount(addr, passwd, 0);// the account is unlocked untill geth stops running.
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess it should be "you can specify the unlock duration..." - and also, an argument of 0 makes the account unlocked indefinitely, right?

Comment: As i know there is no indefinitely unlock

Answer (score 0):

Use any one of the below options

1. testrpc -u Account#
2. testrpc --secure
3. web3.personal.unlockAccount("address", "pass", 0);
4. geth --unlock YOUR_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS --password YOUR_PASSWORD

Comment: Where should I specify `testrpc`?

Comment: yes, 
 testrpc -u your account number

Comment: Is `testrpc` a command? Or is it an argument when invoking `geth`? Or should I write it at the `geth` JS-console? Sorry, I'm new to Ethereum.

Comment: For geth use this geth --unlock <YOUR_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS> --password <YOUR_PASSWORD>

Comment: Thanks, what about `testrpc`?

Comment: testrpc is another client like geth specifically for development

Answer (score 0):

Remix allows you to switch to a JavaScript VM (like TestRPC) that has an account with a lot of Ether and several unlocked accounts - and very quick block times. It is very helpful for learning Solidity and quick development iterations:

[image]